# How to verify passwords created by Django(make_password) without Django

Tags: python, django

I have used Django and handled password with `make_password` and `check_password`.

however, I get to change a framework to `fastapi`.

With `fastapi`, I need to verify passwords that are created by Django because I should use the same database with the data.

How can I handle the passwords in the way that is compatible with Django?

Password's format stored in database is like that `'pbkdf2_sha256$100000$Dl6Atsc1xX0A$0QFvZLpKdcvcmCNixVCdEA5gJ67yef/gkgaCKTYzoo4='`

Comment: You could have django installed but only use the password functions

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, I know that but I don't want to use unnecessary Django only for a password if possible .

Comment: Does the framework you are moving to have it's own authentication package?

Comment: Django is open-source, so you can easily find the relevant part of the code to port it to your "other" framework.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, No It doesn't have but Django is a relatively heavy package I think. that is why I don't want to install Django only for a password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found `passlib` support Django compatible way.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from passlib.handlers.django import django_pbkdf2_sha256

password = 'testpassword123'
django_hash = make_password(password)   
is_verified = django_pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, django_hash)

if is_verified:
  print('Correct!!')
```

Answer (score 1):

This document describes how Django stores passwords:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/

I do something similar to what you're talking about with a Node.js backend. You can split on the `$` character to get the pieces you need to verify a password. Here's a snippet of what I've done:

```js
const [, iterations, salt,] = hash.split('$');
const algorithm = 'pbkdf2_sha256';
salt = (salt === '') ? makeSalt() : salt;
const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, 32, 'sha256');
const rtnval = algorithm + '$' + iterations + '$' + salt + '$' + key.toString('base64');
```

That should get you something you can use to match with the database entry for the given user.

Answer (score 0):

Further to solution from SangminKim, I would like to propose as:

```py
def authenticate_user(db, UserId: str, Password: str):
    user = db.query(orm.Users).filter_by(Id= UserId).first()
    if user:
        if pwd_context.verify(Password, user.Password):
            return user
        elif django_pbkdf2_sha256.verify(Password, user.Password): # in case the password was made with django
            return user
    return False
```

The above code checks the password against FastApi proposed method & in failure case checks against django make_password as the alternative method.